# How to read a music file through NPAPI plugin and play it using <audio> element

Tags: html, npapi, html5-audio

I am playing with the idea of reading an MP3 file from the hard drive and playing it in the browser. I know [one way](https://github.com/antimatter15/player/blob/master/player.html) of doing it - get list of File objects from `<input>` tag, then get their object URL and assign it to `src` of `<audio>`. However there are some drawbacks of this technique (for one, it has to be repeated on every page refresh).

Therefore I am exploring if I can use an NPAPI plugin to read the music file from the HDD and then give it to `<audio>` element somehow. However, I can't figure out how to convert the binary contents of the tile into a File object that javascript can use. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The only option I can think of would be to use a [data: url](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).  I don't know for sure if these are supported in audio tags or not, but they are definitely supported in img tags.

BTW, you are aware that a NPAPI plugin has to be injected into the page in an object tag before it does anything, right? Make sure you know the difference between an extension and a plugin, because what you're talking about sounds more like an extension problem.

Also take a look at [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org); if you do decide to use a NPAPI plugin, that'll simplify your life a lot.